# using a simple dialog fragment in android

Tags: android, timepicker, dialogfragment

### I am trying to launch a timePicker on click of edittext

*I have constructed most of the things !*

**Buffet_offerings_breakfast_menu2.java**

```
import java.util.Calendar;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.text.format.DateFormat;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener;

import com.androidbegin.jsonparsetutorial.R;

public class Buffet_offerings_breakfast_menu2 extends Fragment{

    RadioGroup radioGroup;
    EditText from;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        from=(EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.from_lunch_edit_text_id);

        from.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                // show the time picker dialog
                DialogFragment newFragment = new TimePickerFragment();
                newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "timePicker");
            }
        }); // this is on onCreate() method..

    }

    public void onTimePicked(Calendar time)
    {
        // display the selected time in the TextView
        from.setText(DateFormat.format("h:mm a", time));
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        final View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.buffet_offerings_breakfast_menu2, container, false);


        radioGroup = (RadioGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);        

        radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener(){  
          public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
             // checkedId is the RadioButton selected
                   if(checkedId == R.id.SelectDaysRG_ID)
                   {
                      view.findViewById(R.id.linearLayout_individualdays).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                   }
                   else if(checkedId == R.id.WeekdaysRG_ID)
                   {
                       view.findViewById(R.id.linearLayout_individualdays).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                   }
                   else if(checkedId == R.id.WeekendsRG_ID)
                   {
                       view.findViewById(R.id.linearLayout_individualdays).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                   }

          }
        });


        return view;
    }



}
```

**TimePickerFragment.java**

```
import java.util.Calendar;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.widget.TimePicker;

public class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements OnTimeSetListener
{
    private TimePickedListener mListener;

    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        // use the current time as the default values for the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        // create a new instance of TimePickerDialog and return it
        return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, minute, DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity)
    {
        // when the fragment is initially shown (i.e. attached to the activity), cast the activity to the callback interface type
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try
        {
            mListener = (TimePickedListener) activity;
        }
        catch (ClassCastException e)
        {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement " + TimePickedListener.class.getName());
        }
    }

    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute)
    {
        // when the time is selected, send it to the activity via its callback interface method
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
        c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);

        mListener.onTimePicked(c);
    }

    public static interface TimePickedListener
    {
        public void onTimePicked(Calendar time);
    }
}
```

---

**I am getting two errors as**::

***Error1***::

*for line*

```
 newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "timePicker");
```

*As* -

```
The method getSupportFragmentManager() is undefined for the type new View.OnClickListener(){}
```

***Error2***::

*for line*

```
return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, minute, DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
```

**As** -

```
TimePickerDialog cannot be resolved to a type
```

---

**How can i resolve this !**

Comment: [custom dialogfragment example in android](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=simple+dialogue+fragment+exapmle+in+android&oq=simple+dial&aqs=chrome.3.69i57j0j69i59l2j0l2.7044j0j8&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8#es_sm=93&espv=210&q=custom+dialogfragment+example+in+android)

Comment: look at this http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html

Comment: I used the developer source to build the above code ... how can i corectify my above code

Comment: @smriti3 have you solved?

Comment: @ Piyush Gupta ..... Not yet ! ..... I have made the above code from your yesterdays guidance .... where i need to correct here .... this time i have used in fragment activity ....... can you give me your inputs ?

Comment: @smriti3 Has your Activity extends with FragmentActivity from which your fragment being called???

Answer (score 0):

For the first error you can store the getSupprotFragmentManager() in a private variable declared in the class and then use it here.

Comment: Can you please edit the code as your answer ... i am a new bie

Comment: under the EditText from (in your code)
Declare ..
FragmetManager manager;

in the OnCreate write
manager = getFragmentSupprtManager().

use this variable manager in the OnClickListener.

newFragment.show(manager, "timePicker");

Answer (score 0):

Use getFragmentmanager() instead of getSupportFragmentManager() in your Fragment class. 
Implement TimePickedListener interface in ur FragmentActivity and update the fragment

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements TimePickedListener {

    Calendar time =null;
    Fragment_Main fragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void onTimePicked(Calendar time){
        fragment = (Fragment_Main) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.new_homescreen_two_fragment);
        fragment.onTimePicked(time);
    }

}
```

And this will be in ur fragment.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.buffet_offerings_breakfast_menu2, container, false);
    from = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.etDepDate);

    from.setText("Here");

    from.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // show the time picker dialog
            DialogFragment newFragment = new TimePickerFragment();
            newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "timePicker");
        }
    }); // this is on onCreate() method..
    return view;
}

public void onTimePicked(Calendar time) {
    // display the selected time in the TextView
    from.setText(DateFormat.format("h:mm a", time)); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is from `getSupportFragmentManager()` at `newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "timePicker");`. Your `TimePickerDialog` is a `Fragment`which is committed into `Buffet_offerings_breakfast_menu2` fragment (nested fragment). So use `getChildFragmentManager()` instead of `getSupportFragmentManager()`.